# What to do when c++ say "int is not compatible with int*"?

Tags: c++

What should I use when a thing is declared as `int*` instead of `int`?

```
-> Function: void addIntOption(char *option, int *var, int min, int max)
-> Usage: addIntOption("TEXT", **???**, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: for example `addIntOption("TEXT", &a, 0, 1000);` where `a` is your integer. other options are possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a pointer to it, such as:

```
int var;
addIntOption("TEXT", &var, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a *pointer* to an integer rather than an integer itself, such as with:

```
int xyzzy = 42;
addIntOption("option", &xyzzy, 0, 100);
```

The `&` is the address-of operator which gives you a pointer to (or an address of, if you prefer that terminology) the integer variable `xyzzy`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a step back and pay attention to the error: the function wants a pointer, you want to pass an int. Those are in conflict: *you understand something wrong*. The fix is to figure out what you're misunderstanding.

As the comments suggest, what the function probably wants is for you to "give me a pointer to the `int` value you want modified". This is a common pattern in C when you want a function to modify something. Sometimes it's even useful in C++, although usually you want to use references for that sort of thing.

So, check the documentation; if the above is correct (and you still want to use the function), then you need to obtain a pointer to the value you want modified; e.g. if `var` refers to the object, then `&var` is a pointer to it.

Comment: Is, as ex. char* message using it in the same way? as like drawNotification(char* msg) and drawNotification("Hello " + &username) or how should I do that?

Comment: C-style strings are a whole other can of worms, due mostly to the fact C doesn't have a string type; while you might have gotten used to working with pointers-to-char as if such things were strings, they're really not: they're *pointers to char*; the string is just (an interpretation of) the contents of the memory being pointed to.

Comment: So, can I use this: string test = "Hello, " << myname; or something like that that will work?

Comment: @ZackDaniPoladro No. You can use `strcat` to concatenate a c-style string(i.e. char*), or `string test = "Hello, "; test += myname; drawNotification(test.c_str());` if you use `std::string`.